# Start a -jar with storage parameter

Tags: java

Is ist possible to start a java application with the -X parameters?
I have tried **java -jar -Xmx=256m myAppl.jar** but with no success.
Is there a possibiliy to do this?

Comment: What is "no success"? What you want to do exactly? You want to pass -X parameter to acheive what?

Comment: Because I run into an outOfMemory Exception

Comment: Then you need more than 256 MB. Note that more than 256 MB is suspicious and probably means your OOM is due to other considerations (e.g. memory leaks) than available memory unless you're manipulating several hundred megabytes of data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Xmx parameter does not need `=` symbol, just write Xmx256m
2. It's more convenient to set it before -jar parameter.

   java -Xmx256m -jar myapp.jar

Anyway since you get `OutOfMemoryError`, I think that `=` symbol is just a typo (JVM can't start with invalid Xmx parameter) and the real problem is lack of memory. Try to increase it.